# jQuery XML duplicate append

Tags: jquery, xml, each

I'm new to XML. When I try put in some "cases" into it's XML-parent (called ITEM), it fills into all the ITEMS, and dublicates on some. I have 6 cases, but somehow it shows 12 in one of the ITEMs.

I have an XML-file that looks like this:

```
<menu>
<item>
    <headline />
    <body />
    <cases>
        <case><link /></case>
        <case><link /></case>
        <case><link /></case>
        <case><link /></case>
        <case><link /></case>
        <case><link /></case>
        <case><link /></case>
    </cases>
</item>
<item>
    <headline />
    <body />
</item>
```

On the ITEM that hasn't any cases in it, I don't want any cases to be shown. I only want the cases to be "put into" the right ITEM.

How do I do this?

To display the items, I use:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function(){
    var headline = $("headline", this).text();
    $("ul").append("<li class='" + name + "'><h3>" + headline + "</h3>");

    if ($(xml).find('case').length != 0) {
        //I want it to place this, in the correct ITEM, and not in all items.
        $("ul li").append("<ul class='cases'>");
        $(xml).find('case').each(function(){
            caseLink = $("link", this).text();
            $("ul li .cases").append("<li><a href='" + caseLink + "' /></a></li>");

        });
        $("ul li").append("</ul>");
    }
    $("ul").append("</li>");
});
```

What am I doing wrong???

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I called the (XML) twice.

The second (and the following) time the "if (XML)" is called, use "(this)" instead.

Change:

```
if ($(xml).find
```

To:

```
if ($(this).find
```

That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

thoses line :

```
if ($(xml).find('case').length != 0) {
[...]
$(xml).find('case').each(function(){
```

should be

```
if ((this).find('case').length != 0) {
[...]
(this).find('case').each(function(){
```

or something similar (I did not test it).

Right now, you search inside *xml*, loop on the *item element* and then, search *case element*... in the *xml* instead of the current *item element*.